# Find Scalars of the function using an series.

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

For $ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-x,  & \text{if $\pi<x<0$} \\
x, & \text{if $0<x<\pi$}  \\
\end{cases}$
find scalars $a_0,a_1,...,a_n$ and $b_0,b_1,...,b_n$ such that $f(x)=b_0+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_kcos(kx)+a_ksin(kx)$.

** End Question **

So I don't even get what I'm suppose to do. Where to start is a complete blank.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a question about Fourier series. There are formulas for the $a_j$ and the $b_j$. Wherever you came across this question, I'd be amazed if there was no information about Fourier series there.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't come out of a book. My Linear Algebra professor just wrote it on the board.  And it has nothing to do what we are currently learning in class (Gram-Schmidt Process). That's why I'm so lost.  But thanks. I'll look up Fourier series.

Comment: It may have quite a bit to do with Gram-Schmidt, in the sense that G-S is a way to find an orthonormal basis for an inner product space, and all those sines and cosines form an orthonormal basis for a vector space of functions (given an appropriate inner product on that space).

Answer (score 0):

Note that, you are asked to find the Fourier series of the function $|x|$ which is an even function over the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. That means we only have to find $b_k$

> $$ b_k = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |x|\cos(k x)dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} x\cos(k x)dx =\dots\,, \quad k\geq 0. $$

I think you can finish the problem.

**Note:** Note the orthogonality property of the functions $\sin n x$ and $\cos n x$ over the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$

> $$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(nx)\cos(mx)dx=\begin{cases}0,\quad m\neq n \\ \pi, \quad m=n. \end{cases}, $$
>
> $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(nx)\sin(mx)dx=\begin{cases}0,\quad m\neq n \\ \pi, \quad m=n. \end{cases}.$$
>
> $$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(nx)\cos(mx)dx=0. $$